# what is the equivalent in wpf  for System.Windows.Forms.Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width

Tags: wpf

I'm trying to convert the windows application to wpf application, and everything is fine but i was Struck at this point converting the bellow declaration not working out in code of wpf.

these are windows declarations,

Dim screenwidth As String = System.Windows.Forms.Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width

Dim screenheight As String = System.Windows.Forms.Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height

i googled to find the equivalent class properties for these declarations and i got some thing, but those are existing but not working at the point of time i'm trying to use them at

"**PointToScreen(New Point(0,0))**" 
they are:

If i use these in my code:

Dim screenwidth As String = System.Windows.SystemParameters.VirtualScreenWidth
Dim screenheight As String = System.Windows.SystemParameters.VirtualScreenHeight
'(OR)

Dim screenwidth As String = System.Windows.SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenWidth
Dim screenheight As String = System.Windows.SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenHeight

```
       With MyPanel
            .PointToScreen(New Point(SystemParameters.VirtualScreenWidth, 0)) ' Getting Exception in this line               
            .Height = (80 / 1080) * screenheight
            .Width = screenwidth                
            .Background = New SolidColorBrush(Colors.Transparent)
        End With
```

Am getting the exception as Invalid Operation Exception saying that
"The visual is not connected to PresentationSource."

i alreadt tried this post http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/wpf/thread/f3c982a1-ca16-4821-bf08-f6dd8ff8d829
, but i want to try it out using PointToScreen only.

How can i resolve this ????
Please help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi try this to get the Width and height of screen.

```
double width=System.Windows.SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenWidth;
double height = System.Windows.SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenHeight;
```

The exception is because you are pointing Mypanel before it is rendered. Do it like this

```
if (MyPanel.IsVisible)
        { 
            MyPanel
            .PointToScreen(New Point(SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenWidth, 0)) ' Getting Exception in this line               
            .Height = (80 / 1080) * screenheight
            .Width = screenwidth                
            .Background = New SolidColorBrush(Colors.Transparent)
        }
```

I hope this will help.

Comment: I already tried this, at that time also am getting the same exception that "The visual is not connected to PresentationSource." Can you please tell me the exact solution for this...!

Comment: The Exception is not because of this, Exception is because of MyPanel. Can you please show your xaml.

Comment: am creating my panel dynamically only. like Private WithEvents MyPanel As System.Windows.Controls.Canvas

Comment: Yes, if i use isvisible condition then it's not going inside. i think i need to make it visible before that know. But after setting myCanvas.Visibility =true also it's not getting inside the loop. how can i do get the control to inside loop??? please suggest me

Comment: Yes thats where exception is .Your control must render before it can be PointToScreen.

Comment: I think you in wrong direction.You havent added MyPanel to Window then how you can expect it to Point to Screen.Update your question and show your xaml and ask tell where exactly you want MyPanel to be.

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.Height
```

and

```
Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.Width
```

If you want to consider DPI settings, I use this (_windowToControl is a window in your application):

```
    public double ScreenPixelHeight
    {
        get
        {
            PresentationSource source = PresentationSource.FromVisual(_windowToControl);
            if (source != null)
                return Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.Height * source.CompositionTarget.TransformFromDevice.M11;
            else
                return 0;
        }
    }
    public double ScreenPixelWidth
    {
        get
        {
            PresentationSource source = PresentationSource.FromVisual(_windowToControl);
            if (source != null)
                return Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.Width * source.CompositionTarget.TransformFromDevice.M11;
            else
                return 0;
        }
    }
```